# How can I get Cassandra List type from SQL statement in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, cassandra, cql3

I create a connection to Cassandra DB using a SQL data source, and I want to execute select query using `Statement.execute()`.

My Cassandra table has a List type

```
CREATE TABLE tableX (
id bigint,
average_value List<double>
);
```

My Code to retrieve the result is

```
import java.sql.*;
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:jboss/datasources/ds");
Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
Statement stmnt = connection.createStatement();
Resultset rs = stmnt.execute("select * from tableX;");
if (rs != null) {
    obj.put("average_value",rs.getObject("average_value "));
}
```

But, when I try to get `average_value` from the result set, I get this exception

> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: the Cassandra implementation
>   does not support this method

**Update**

When I use getObject it worked well , but the select query itself is return the empty list, although list has a values in DB

So how can get values of list not empty one ?

Comment: Obviously, given the error, the Cassandra JDBC driver doesn't support this method. What is your actual question?

Comment: How to get list type from stmnt.execute("select * from tableX;");

Comment: when I get it using getObject() it worked but now the Issue is that the select query return empty list